# how to test ruby inheritance with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to test logic that runs during class inheritance, but have run into an issue when running multiple assertions.

i first tried...

```
describe 'self.inherited' do
  before do
    class Foo
      def self.inherited klass; end
    end

    Foo.stub(:inherited)

    class Bar < Foo; end
  end

  it 'should call self.inherited' do
    # this fails if it doesn't run first
    expect(Foo).to have_received(:inherited).with Bar
  end

  it 'should do something else' do
    expect(true).to eq true
  end
end
```

but this fails because the Bar class has already been loaded, and therefore does not call `inherited` a 2nd time.  If the assertion doesn't run first... it fails.

So then i tried something like...

```
describe 'self.inherited once' do
  before do
    class Foo
      def self.inherited klass; end
    end

    Foo.stub(:inherited)

    class Bar < Foo; end
  end

  it 'should call self.inherited' do
    @tested ||= false
    unless @tested
      expect(Foo).to have_receive(:inherited).with Bar
      @tested = true
    end
  end

  it 'should do something else' do
    expect(true).to eq true
  end
end
```

because `@tested` doesn't persist from test to test, the test doesn't just run once.

anyone have any clever ways to accomplish this?  This is a contrived example and i dont *actually* need to test ruby itself ;)

Comment: Test the behaviour, not implementation. Testing if class inherits from come class would be reasonable only if the method is doing meta programming stuff (like constructing class and sets anccestors)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here's an easy way to test for class inheritance with RSpec:

Given

```
class A < B; end
```

a much simpler way to test inheritance with RSpec would be:

```
describe A do
  it { expect(described_class).to be < B }
end
```

Comment: Nice answer!  The explanation could be found here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-3C

Answer (score 11):

For something like this

```
class Child < Parent; end
```

I usually do:

```
it 'should inherit behavior from Parent' do
  expect(Child.superclass).to eq(Parent)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, I did not manage the [solution from David Posey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32655436/1532897) to work (I guess I did something wrong. Feel free to provide a solution in the comments). In case someone out there have the same problem, this works too:

```
describe A
  it { expect(described_class.superclass).to be B }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your class definition for testing inheritance run during the test:

```
describe 'self.inherited' do

  before do
    class Foo
      def self.inherited klass; end
    end
    # For testing other properties of subclasses
    class Baz < Foo; end 
  end

  it 'should call self.inherited' do
    Foo.stub(:inherited)
    class Bar < Foo; end
    expect(Foo).to have_received(:inherited).with Bar
  end

  it 'should do something else' do
    expect(true).to eq true
  end
end
```

Comment: so simple... just use a different class for that single test... of course! thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't we remove the class definition on an `after` callback? According to the name of the class, I would say it could have had side effects.  
`Object.send(:remove_const, :Foo)` maybe?

Comment: @brcebn The idea here is that `Bar` is a throwaway class used only in the test. You can make it more throwaway and re-usable across multiple spec examples by using an anonymous class e.g. `let(:target_class) { Class.new(Foo) }`

Comment: I get your idea. Thanks for clarifying. 

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
class Foo; end
class Bar < Foo; end
class Baz; end

RSpec.describe do
  it 'is inherited' do
    expect(Bar < Foo).to eq true
  end

  it 'is not inherited' do
    expect(Baz < Foo).not_to eq true
  end
end
```